# Calculate effective work hours

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to calculate effective work hours of specific device. My database is like that:

```
-------------------------------------
timestamp - device - status
-------------------------------------
2017-01-25 11:00:00 - devicename - 1
2017-01-25 11:00:00 - devicename - 0
-------------------------------------
```

**1** - represents work

**0** - represents not working

i'm using this sql query to get todays data from database:

```
SELECT * FROM device WHERE timestamps >= CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY timestamps ASC
```

but my problem is i can't think of any solution with php how to calculate how much hours it's working effective. More specifically how much hours was working and how much was not working today.

Maybe someone has any ideas how i could solve this problem.

Assuming that work day starts 8AM and ends 6PM.

Comment: You need to show us more data here.  Based on the sample, we can't even tell anything.

Comment: how will you calculate total working hours ? only behalf of timestamp field ? is there hidden total number of working hours or out time for office which is rigid ? In short, inadequate data.

Comment: That is my problem that it logs time when it's working or not every 30sec. to database. There is no total working hours, cuz devices posts data too.

Comment: If you can guarantee the updates are every 30 seconds, you could query for something like `SELECT SUM(status) * 30 AS seconds FROM device WHERE device = "deviceName" AND --a clause for determining the time period`